# How to Replace Const With Other Valua In Java Script

Tags: javascript

i have Constanta In Javascript , i want to replace This Value Before Initialitate this conts but not working , i have idea to replacing Const With Other Const but This not Working again

```js
const audioMap = [
    "<?php echo base_url('sounds/Airport_Bell.mp3');?>",
    "<?php echo base_url('sounds/C.wav'); ?>"
];

self.queue.shift();

document.getElementById("list_antrian").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(self.queue);

let audio = new Audio();

function playSequence(sounds) {

    const playNextSounds = (sounds) => {
        if (sounds.length > 0) {
            var audio = new Audio();
            audio.src = sounds[0];
            audio.currentTime = 0;
            audio.play();
            sounds.shift();
            audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                return playNextSounds(sounds);
            })
        } else {
            self._call();
        }
    }

    let currentSoundIndex = 0;

    if (sounds.length > 0) {
        const audio = new Audio();
        audio.src = sounds[0];
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
        sounds.shift();

        audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            return playNextSounds(sounds);
        })
    } else {
        self._call();
    }

}

playSequence([
    "<?php echo base_url('sounds/A.wav'); ?>",
    "<?php echo base_url('sounds/B.wav'); ?>",
    "<?php echo base_url('sounds/C.wav'); ?>"
]);
```

I want Change playSequence With audioMap

Thanks

Comment: Is it nessary for you to use `constant` or not? If not, try to use `var` or `let`

Comment: As it's written now, your question is unclear. Please elaborate on the issue you are facing.

Comment: You are either not including the code where you are attempting to actually solve the problem, or your question doesn't make sense. Please provide where you are actually attempting to achieve what you are describing. What's actually stopping you from switching out the values? Literally just replace the array contents of playSequence with your audioMap. If you need the audioMap to change values at a later stage, declare it as a `let` instead of a const.

Answer (score 0):

use `let` when mutating, `const` when it's constant.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

You can merge those array's together, like in the following, if you're trying to just bring in `audioMap` and the array currently being passed into `playSequence`

```
const audioMap = [
  "<?php echo base_url('sounds/Airport_Bell.mp3');?>",
  "<?php echo base_url('sounds/C.wav'); ?>"
];
const audioSet = [
  "<?php echo base_url('sounds/A.wav'); ?>",
  "<?php echo base_url('sounds/B.wav'); ?>",
  "<?php echo base_url('sounds/C.wav'); ?>"
]
playSequence([...audioSet, ...audioMap]);
```

You can also mutate the array, but I recommend the approach above.

Comment: how to replace const playSequence With audioMap

Comment: `playSequence` is a function, are you trying to pass `audioMap` into `playSequence` ? in which case it would be `playSequence(audioMap)` or are you trying to update after `playSequence` has  executed?